# ExpressJS: How can I make Jade compilation less verbose?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

Here's the problem: When I spin up an expressjs 3.x server, I would like to do console.log to look into certain variables. However, that output gets buried under text from Jade compiler output.

I tried passing this option, but it didn't work:

```
app.set("view options", {
  compileDebug: false
});
```

Any ideas on how I can make Jade output less info when compiling?

**Edit:**

After accepting the answer below I discovered the solution which I needed. Namely, configuring express.logger which is based on [connect-logger](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/middleware-logger.html) (or exactly the same?).

Find the line in your app.js which says

```
app.use(express.logger("dev"));
```

And change it to

```
app.use(express.logger("tiny"));
```

**Voila!** An output which makes it easier to see your console.log output for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the migration guide here https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x

Has a section on view option changes. If you want to set the compiler debug to false you would do so thusly:

`app.locals.compileDebug = false`

Comment: Thanks. :) It was a good step in the right direction. I'm now getting a more compact text cloud consisting of the generated html, but I guess that's as close as I get towards making expressjs a tad more silent. Marking this as solved since I don't know if it's possible to make the jade compilation even more silent.

Comment: Unless you hack jade's core of course which obviously has it's own inherent issues. Post an issue asking for a `--silent` flag. TJ is pretty good about rolling in feature requests and I definitely think this would be a good candidate. Glad I could help =)